# How to pass variable to LIKE wildcard

Tags: sql

I'm trying to delete temp table names from the APPDB by getting the list from the DOMDB.
I can't find or figure out how the syntax in SQL should be.

This is some sort of a combination of two codes that works separately but I thought of combining the two to iterate on the list.

```
USE DOMDB
Declare @OPR_CODE char( 11 )
SET rowcount 0
SELECT OPR_CODE into #TEMPOPR from DOMN_OPR
SET rowcount 1
SELECT @OPR_CODE = OPR_CODE from #TEMPOPR

USE APPDB
DECLARE @OPRCODE NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @OPRCODE += '
DROP TABLE ' 
   + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
   + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE name LIKE '% + OPR_CODE + 001%';
--something like if OPR_CODE='USER' it will be (WHERE name LIKE '%USER001%';

EXEC sp_executesql @OPRCODE;

while @@rowcount <> 0
begin
set rowcount 0
select * from #TEMPOPR where OPR_CODE = @OPR_CODE
delete #TEMPOPR where OPR_CODE = @OPR_CODE

set rowcount 1
select @OPR_CODE = OPR_CODE from #TEMPOPR
end
set rowcount 0
DROP table #TEMPOPR
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper concatenation:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%' + @OPR_CODE + '001%'
```

Comment: Thanks Wolf, the proper concatenation works, but the iteration that i wish to happen sort of breaks after the

    EXEC sp_executesql @OPRCODE;

it could not pick up the rest of the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This way? `LIKE '% +&'+@OPR_CODE+'&+001%';`